# declaring variables without any data type in c

Tags: c, variables

In this `c` program

```
a=8;
main()
{
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

variable a has been declared without any data type and still this program compiles successfully and gives the desired output.
output ::

```
8
```

see it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/NioWM).
but, when i declared the same variable inside main, it gives compilation error.

```
main()
{
     a=8;
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

output ::

```
prog.c:2: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:3: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
prog.c:3: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
prog.c:3: error: for each function it appears in.)
prog.c:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’
prog.c:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
```

see [here](http://ideone.com/2hILX).

**How the first program is working but the second?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you see here is the **["Implicit Int Rule"](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=467)** at work. Simply put the rule says:

> "A ***variable declared*** without an explicit type name is assumed to be of type `int`."

Note that this rule was revoked in the c99 Standard<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>.However, depending on your compiler and its settings, the first example might compile with a warning, or will fail to compile(*with strict compilation settings*)

If you compile your first example with strict settings adhering to c99 Standard the compiler will tell you the root cause.

check **[here](http://ideone.com/AMMQm)**.

> cc1: warnings being treated as errors
>   prog.c:1: error: data definition has no type or storage class
>   prog.c:1: error: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘a’
>   prog.c:3: error: return type defaults to ‘int’
>   prog.c: In function ‘main’:
>   prog.c:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’
>   prog.c:4: error: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’

EDIT:

> **why does the first example work but second does not?**

Note the emphasis on the words "variable declared" in the rule.

In first example, since the statement is at the global scope it is treated as an ***Implicit declaration***, and the *Implicit Int Rule* gets applied to it.

In Second example, the statement acts as an ***Assignment and not a Declaration***. Since there is no declaration the *Implicit int rule* does not apply here. In the absence of any type the compiler cannot determine what is the type of `a` and hence reports the error.

---

<sup>[Ref 1]</sup>

**C99 Standard: Foreword**
**Para 5:**

> This edition replaces the previous edition, `ISO/IEC 9899:1990`, as amended and corrected
>   by `ISO/IEC 9899/COR1:1994`, `ISO/IEC 9899/COR2:1995`, and `ISO/IEC 9899/AMD1:1995`.
>   Major changes from the previous edition include:
>   .....
>   .....
>   — remove implicit int
>   .....
>   .....

Comment: I do feel it has value. For a more complete answer, though, you might explain that in the second example, `a = 8` is an assignment, not a declaration.

Comment: For the first program, you said `main()` function defaults to `int`. But it compiled successfully even when i just called `return;`(without any value) in main. How is that possible?

Comment: @nitish712: You will need to compile your program by enabling all compiler warnings. `-Wall` in case you are using gcc. C and C++ standards do not require compilers to check whether a function returns a value in all code paths & so by default compilers will not provide this diagnostic, You need to explicitly tell the compiler to do so.Also, note that w.r.t functions `main` is though a function is given a special treatment by the standards in some regards, You may want to check the standards for these rules.

Comment: The first link is dead.

Answer (score 8):

`a=8;` outside of the function looks like a **declaration statment**, where `a` is the declaration specifier and `= 8` is the initializer. C used to allow to omit types in declaration specifiers and defaults to `int` in that case. (Since C99, this is no longer allowed.)

However, in a function, `a=8;` looks like an **expression statement** (an assignment expression) and symbol `a` isn't resolved. (Note that you don't have expression statements outside of functions.)

If you tried to do, for instance `static a = 8;`, then it would again look like a declaration, and should compile because the type would default to int.

Anyway, don't rely on that :-) Write your types clearly.

Answer (score 3):

It's because in C, any variable / function is implicitly `int`.

This is the same reason that you can use `register` instead of `register int`, or `unsigned` instead of `unsigned int`, `auto` instead of `auto int`, and `static` instead of `static int`. I personally always explicitly qualify my variables with `int`, but whether you do or not is your option.

Comment: In Shakespearean C.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable does have a data type (int) even though you didn't write the data type.

It is bad practice to take advantage of that feature.

Apparently your compiler doesn't allow that to happen inside a function.  That makes sense because if it did allow "a=8;" in a function it would be very hard to catch certain typoes.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, there is the `auto`
 keyword.Unfortunately,  C and C++ are strongly-typed languages, whose require defining a strict type for the each declared variable. Some compliers assume int as default , but it's their well-mind and it should not be used, because it's acknowledged
as a wrong programming habit.

Comment: This question is about C rather than C++. C is a language with a standard that can be used to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

even a function parameter can be written as implicit int.
example:

```
fun(n){printf("%d",n);}
```

The above code works fine but once a fixed datatype is included in parameters,like

```
fun(n,char c){ printf("%d",n);}
```

It shows error:
error: expected ')' before 'char'|

Comment: This is a separate issue to the question. `fun(n)` introduces a K&R-style function definition