# Implicit int declaration of a variable when type qualifier is specified

Tags: c, gcc

I was learning about `const` type qualifier and I accidentally wrote the following code which I compiled with `gcc -Wall -Wextra`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const a = 5;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler throws this warning:

```
warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘a’ [-Wimplicit-int]
     const a = 5;
           ^
```

The ouptut of the program is `5`. I tried to change `const` with other type qualifiers like `volatile` and `_Atomic` and I have got the same result. I tried to use `restrict` but I have got an error because I think this keyword is expecting a pointer.

My question is, is there any syntactic rule in the C standard, that requires from compilers to implicitly set to int the the type of a variable specified by a type qualifier without a specific type, or is it gcc specific extension?

Comment: Yes, if the type is not specified it defaults to `int`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189962/implicit-int-in-c-language

Comment: This was allowed until C99, now not. Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11064331/8359764

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488502/which-section-in-c89-standard-allows-the-implicit-int-rule