# Why does gcc produce an error for implicit declaration of functions returning not int?

Tags: c, function, declaration

There are a few similar questions asking people to debug their code, where the compiler produces a warning of implicit declaration of functions. I know that this warning is produced because if a function is used without there being a prior declaration, function calls can be treated as implicit declarations.

This code has an *intentional* bug for educational purposes.
There are two implicitly declared functions here: one returns `int`, the second function returns **another data type** which is `char*`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    function1();
    function2();
}

int function1(void)
{
    printf("function1\n");
    return 2;
}

char* function2(void)
{
    char* word = "function2\n";
    printf(word);
    return word;
}
```

When I go to compile this code, I get these warnings, and an **error**:

```
$ gcc test1.c
test1.c: In function ‘main’:
test1.c:5:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘function1’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     function1();
     ^
test1.c:6:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘function2’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     function2();
     ^
test1.c: At top level:
test1.c:15:7: error: conflicting types for ‘function2’
 char* function2(void)
       ^
test1.c:6:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘function2’ was here
     function2();
     ^
```

First I created the `function1` and I was able to compile and run the code without problems. The implicit declaration of `int function1()` was accepted, even though the compiler produced some warnings.

Then I created the `function2` and to my surprise, an **error** was produced by the compiler and the code rejected. Why was the implicit declaration of `char* function2()` not accepted? Why didn't the function call as an implicit declaration work?

This is the error:

```
error: conflicting types for ‘function2’
```

What is the conflicting type? There is only one type. The function takes no arguments and returns `char*`.

Why did it work for `function1`?

Comment: It varies by compiler, but many compilers, when they see an implicit function, simply mark it as 'function returning integer'. So, it defines  ```function2``` implicitly as ```int function2()```, but then tries to redefine later on as ```char* function2()```.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi So it does that for function *calls* too?

Comment: `int`eresting stuff

Comment: Seems to be similar to the implicit variables as `int`s rule:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064292/declaring-variables-without-any-data-type-in-c

Comment: In C90, you could implicitly declare functions and be OK as long as the eventual definition agreed with the implicit declaration.  Thus, `function1` was (sort of) OK in C90, but `function2` was not because the assumed return type was incorrect  In C99 (and later), you are supposed to have a declaration (or definition) of each function in scope before you use the function.  Ideally, that should be a prototype declaration so that the function parameter types can be checked.  GCC 5.1 and later defaults to C11 mode compilation; earlier versions defaulted to C90 mode.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler unfortunately even the latest version of gcc still defaults to not issuing an error for calling an undeclared function

Comment: It gives a warning, though, doesn't it, @M.M?  At least for me, my home-built GCC 9.1.0 on macOS 10.14.5 Mojave yields: `x.c:4:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘another_func’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]` —— 
`4 |     return another_func(x / 2) + 37;`.  Since I normally compile with `-Werror`, that becomes an error for me. File `x.c` has 5 lines: `extern int somefunc(int x); int somefunc(int x) { return another_func(x / 2) + 37; }`; each brace is on a line of its own.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It gives warning only, but no error. Doesn't stop you from compiling and making the executable.

Comment: @Galaxy — in my book, you should be using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror` as the default compiler flags to GCC. Using `-Werror` converts warnings into errors; it prevents sloppy code from being compiled (including `int main() { … }` — that needs to be `int main(void) { … }`).  I seldom run code that doesn't compile cleanly under those options — when I do, it is usually someone else's grubby code that doesn't yet meet my standards, or I'm testing "what happens if …".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Testing is fun!