# Is "data definition has no type or storage class" valid in C?

Tags: c, types, int, implicit

In C language, we can declare variable without data type. Like this example

```
#include<stdio.h>

i=5,j=10;
int main()
{
    printf("i = %d\nj = %d \n",i,j);
}
```

When we do not mention the datatype of variable, compiler generates warning:

```
prog.c:3:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
    3 | i=5,j=10;
      | ^
prog.c:3:1: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'i' [-Wimplicit-int]
prog.c:3:5: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'j' [-Wimplicit-int]
    3 | i=5,j=10;
      |     ^
```

This means that its implicitly defined as `int`.

So, Is it valid or undefined behavior?

Comment: Implicit `int` is valid in very old versions of C, invalid in new versions of C and still supported by some compilers. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Yes new compiler also support implicit int.

Comment: C99 and later does not allow implicit `int`.  You shouldn’t abuse the system by using what was outlawed 20 years ago.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Correct me if I'm wrong, but C90 didn't allow implicit int for variable declarations either. Just for missing function declaration return types, K&R style function parameters etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hello sir, it's still allow in new version of C. You can see : https://wandbox.org/permlink/WzCG6Vk7LvY4LMOs

Comment: @msc — no, it isn’t. The compiler may or may not complain, but the standard doesn’t allow it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [declaring variables without any data type in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064292/declaring-variables-without-any-data-type-in-c) @JonathanLeffler You could close this obvious dupe, thx.

Comment: @Lundin — C90 allowed both global variables and function parameters with implicit `int`, as well as implicit function declarations.  Local variables had to be declared, but `auto n;` was sufficient — the type was implicitly `int`. It was fairly pointless to type 4 letters instead of 3.  But `register` worked too, as did `static`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok then my answer isn't correct. I'll delete it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not sure if `i = 5;` (with no type-specifiers nor storage-class-specifiers) was legal. The copy of C89 I have is badly formatted but the grammar spec for external declarations doesn't seem to just allow *declarator* with nothing else